# Analyse ordinal data between subjects

Tags: ordinal-data, friedman-test

I have two groups of participants, group 1 looked at four images under condition 1, and group 2 looked at the four images under condition 2. I want to see whether the condition influenced the order in which they looked at the four images. Here is what my data looks like:

| participant | Condition | Image | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | P | I-1 | 1 |
| P1 | P | I-2 | 3 |
| P1 | P | I-3 | 2 |
| P1 | P | I-4 | 4 |
| P2 | E | I-1 | 4 |

I am not sure what test to be used, I have been suggested to use the Friedman test, but the test is for within-subject treatment, and my experiment was between subjects. Is Mann-Whitney a suitable alternative in this case?

Comment: Friedman's test will only work for data arranged in unreplicated complete block design.  Your data doesn't fit this design.  (Because you want to account for two effects (*Condition* and *Image*) along with a blocking variable (*Participant*).  ...  Since your dependent variable is ordinal in nature, you will probably want to use ordinal regression.   A good implementation of this method will allow for a mixed-effects model, where you can treat *Condition* and *Image* as fixed effects, and *Participant* as a random effect, if that makes sense for your design and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Answer from my comment:***

Friedman's test will only work for data arranged in unreplicated complete block design. Your data doesn't fit this design. Because you want to account for two effects (*Condition* and *Image*) along with a blocking variable (*Participant*).

Since your dependent variable is ordinal in nature, you will probably want to use ordinal regression. A good implementation of this method will allow for a mixed-effects model, where you can treat *Condition* and *Image* as fixed effects, and *Participant* as a random effect, if that makes sense for your design and data.